# Can meson.build files be divided into distinct files? How?

Tags: build, meson-build

I would like to split up my meson.build file into multiple files, for ease of management and sharing across projects.

One way to do this might be via `subdir`.  However, I'd rather not put `meson.build` files throughout my source tree.

Is there another way to accomplish this? Something like `import another-meson.build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to load another build file is via `subdir()`, or via `subproject()` and `dependency()`. In each case, the filename must be `meson.build`. I believe there was some discussion around the idea of having an `include(filename: str)` method which would provide the type of behaviour you're after, but I don't recall if there was any traction on that matter.